# C# SQL Linq get all duplicates

Tags: mysql, linq, c#-4.0

Please tell me how to to solve the problem.

I have to sequences (numbersA and numbersB ). On the output I need only elements that available in the second sequence (numbersB).

int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9 }; 
int[] numbersB = { 2, 4 };

numbersA - numbersB  = 2, 4 ,4

Except() or Intersect() are dosen' t work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var result = numbersA.Where(x => numbersB.Contains(x));
```

That's okay if `numbersB` is very small, but as it gets larger you'd probably want to change to:

```
var numbersBSet = new HashSet<int>(numbersB);
var result = numbersA.Where(x => numbersBSet.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashSet from the second list so lookups are fast, and then just do:

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9 }; 
int[] numbersB = { 2, 4 };
var set = new HashSet<int>(numbersB);
var finalList = numbersA.Where(n => set.Contains(n));
```